# Would a tourist visa work for attending job interview in Germany

Tags: change-purpose-of-travel, schengen-visas

I am a citizen of India, and I have to attend a job interview in Germany. Is it OK (according to German govt rules) to attend a job interview with a tourist visa?

If not what other visa should I be applying?

I did a internet search and found conflicting answers, so an answer citing official source would be really helpful.

Comment: Do you already have a visa?

Comment: Can you link to some of the conflicting answers? They may not be as contradictory as you think. Or, if some of the information is incorrect, we may be able to explain exactly why it is incorrect.

Comment: Hopefully, the job interviewer is not asking you some money for the interview ? Companies that are ready to spend money for a job interview from India to Germany usually are also dealing with the visa issues.

Answer (score 4):

In Germany (and the rest of the Schengen area), there is no such thing as a “tourist visa” but only short-stay visas covering many different purposes. Actual work requires an additional permission (before you apply for the visa) but attending a job interview typically does not.

Importantly, the application form has a box where you specify the purpose of the trip. Simply check “Other” and write “Job interview” (do submit evidence that you have been invited to a job interview, e.g. a letter from your prospective employer, as well). This way, the purpose of the trip will be completely unambiguous and you will know that your visa was issued with this in mind.

There is also such a thing as a “job search” visa but my understanding is that it is intended for people who want to stay in Germany looking for a job for more than three months (up to six I think), not for people who just want to go in and out for an interview. You could always ask the consulate about that one however (be aware however that very few of those are issued every year, you really need stellar qualifications and, this being Germany, quite a bit of paperwork to get one).